# Error loading OpenCV XML file with Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.1 and Python 2.7 (Enthought EPD 7.3 running under Visual Studio Python Tools). I'm trying to read an xml file using OpenCV Load() function:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

reprojectionError=cv2.Load("calib.xml")
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
    reprojectionError=cv2.Load("calib.xml")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Load'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try cv2.cv.Load or cv2.core.Load?

Comment: Right, it seems I have to use cv2.cv.Load. This posting is also relevant: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226258/why-does-python-cv2-modules-depend-on-old-cv)

Comment: Now I'm getting a different error:

`OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The node does not represent a user
object (unknown type?)) in unknown function, file
C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 4961`

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same error. After searching, I found out some discussion on it in OpenCV bug tracker. From their discussion, what I understood is (of course there are lot of things i couldn't understand like some encoding etc), OpenCV load only valid xml file.

Valid means, it should be some OpenCV structures like IplImage, cvSeq etc. Otherwise it throws some errors.

When I tried to load a haarcascade xml file, It returned NULL.

```
TypeError: OpenCV returned NULL
```

When I tried to load some arbitrary xml, (got from somewhere,not related to OpenCV):

```
error: The node does not represent a user object (unknown type?)
```

Finally, I loaded an image, saved it in xml file using cv.Save, and tried to load it as follows :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.cv.LoadImage('0.jpg',0)
cv2.cv.Save('sof.xml',img)
e=cv2.cv.Load("sof.xml")

print e
```

And I got the following result, which is correct :

```
<iplimage(nChannels=1 width=300 height=300 widthStep=300 )>
```

So what I understood from these examples and discussions on bug tracker is that OpenCV loads only xml files with valid OpenCV structures in it. (And it is a good option. Why should OpenCV try to load all the xml files out there? It have to open only files related to it).

This is what i know about this. Hope it helps !!!

Comment: The XML file that I'm trying to load is actually valid XML generated by OpenCV (the first lines are `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>`. This file contains camera calibration data, and it was generated by a 3rd party application using OpenCV. Looking at the OpenCV documentation, it seems that I should be able to load it using the `FileStorage` class, however I do not see any Python bindings for it... Maybe I should use a generic Python XML library?

Comment: Well, I am sorry, i don't have much idea about it.

Comment: Any news about this issue ? Is there any way to load xml file containing sequences of cvmat with python ?

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV IO in Python is pretty poor currently. I believe in the current master it's there under FileNode, but the documentation is non-existent right now. Presumably, you're expected to use standard methods from Numpy (since OpenCV mats are exposed as Numpy arrays in Python).

The `cv` module is also deprecated, so `Load` doesn't exist any more.

Anyway, here's a quick function to load a Mat from an OpenCV XML file. I gave up trying to get it to work natively with OpenCV, it was simpler just to use a parser:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np

def load_from_opencv_xml(filename, elementname, dtype='float32'):
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        rows = int(tree.find(elementname).find('rows').text)
        cols = int(tree.find(elementname).find('cols').text)
        return np.fromstring(tree.find(elementname).find('data').text, dtype, count=rows*cols, sep=' ').reshape((rows, cols))
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
        return None
```

Should cover the majority of uses where you've saved something in C++ like:

```
cv::FileStorage right_fs("right_calibration.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
right_fs << "cameraMatrix" << right_camera_matrix;
right_fs.release();
```

Tested with OpenCV 3 and Python 3, but should be fine on 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I found I could load camera matrix and distortion coefficients from an XML file saved by the cv calibration app using the python cv (not cv2) API's Load(). You have to specify the file name, and the name of the object in that file.

```
import cv
import numpy

calib_filename = '/path/to/my/output/of/calibration.xml'

camera_matrix = numpy.asarray(cv.Load(calib_filename, cv.CreateMemStorage(), 'camera_matrix'))
dist_coeffs = numpy.asarray(cv.Load(calib_filename, cv.CreateMemStorage(), 'distortion_coefficients'))
```

Note the wrap in numpy.asarray() to turn the CvMat returned by cv.Load() into a numpy array, cv2-style, since it looks like you are trying to work in cv2 (as am I).

Worked for me in OpenCV 2.4.3, python 2.7, on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while loading the haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml file.
so i just downloaded the file required from the link below

https://code.google.com/p/jviolajones/downloads/detail?name=haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

pasted it at a specific location , gave the right path in the code and i ran my code sucessfully

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of your code with us so that other users can see the solution that worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I used debug libs in release mode so it gave error. when I changed debug lib(xd.lib) to release lib (x.lib) it worked.

Sinan